# Is the solution-set to |x – a| < d the same as that of |a – x| < d?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is the solution-set to |x – a| < d, where x is a variable, a is a constant, and d is a positive constant, the same as that of |a – x| < d?

I guess so, since both mean "the distance between x and a is less than d", but how to prove/understand that it's so?

Comment: Since $\lvert x-a\rvert=\lvert a-x\rvert$…

Comment: If you want to prove something rigorously, you need definitions to work with. What is your _definition_ of absolute value? If it's just "distance", then that's it, the distance from $x$ to $a$ is clearly the same as the distance from $a$ to $x$, proof done. Other definitions require other proofs.

Answer (score 2):

Use that $$x-a=(-1)(a-x)$$ so $$|x-a|=|a-x|$$